# Como chamar uma função javascript após um download no webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Tenho uma página aspx com um grid e um linkbutton. Ao clicar nesse linkbutton chamo uma função que trava a tela e coloca um loading enquanto realizo o download de um arquivo no servidor, após o download tento chamar a função para destravar a tela, porém o mesmo não chama pois o response já foi finalizado. tentei realizar via iframe mas não sei como enviar esse mesmo arquivo para ser baixado no iframe.

seguem meus códigos.

**Quando clico no linkbutton do grid**

*Código do script*

```
$('#meugrid').find('a').click(function () { ForceBlock(); });
```

*Código do linkbutton no codebehind*

```
protected void linkbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(lb.CommandArgument);

            FileInfo arquivo = new FileInfo("meuarquivo");
            string path = @"meucaminho\";

                File.WriteAllBytes(path + arquivo.FileName, arquivo);

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + arquivo.FileName);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", arquivo.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.TransmitFile(path + arquivo.FileName);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();

                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();


            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "scriptUnblock", "ForceUnblock()", true);

    }
```

Comment: Algum erro no console?

Comment: não, nenhum erro...

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, criando um Generic Handler com o código de download. Na minha página chamo uma função js que passa a url desse .ashx para um iframe invisivel, essa .ashx faz o download e depois na minha página chamo minha outra função para desbloquear a UI.